# Save class to file from URLClassLoader? and decompile it?

Tags: java, decompiling, urlclassloader

It's possible to save class from URLClassLoader to normal file.class? and then decompile it?

I trying save it just as object using

```
        Class<?> clazz = classLoader.loadClass("foo.Bar");
        FileOutputStream sf = new FileOutputStream(f);
        ObjectOutputStream s = new ObjectOutputStream(sf);
        s.writeObject(clazz);
        s.close();
```

Bu that don't work.

So... how to decompile it? I need get something like result of jd-gui, but using class from URLClassLoader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map the class name (e.g. `"foo.Bar"`) to a resource path name (e.g. `"/foo/Bar.class"`) and then use `classLoader.getResourceAsStream` to open a stream to read the bytecode file.

In theory, this can then be fed to a decompiler ... assuming that you have a decompiler that can read from an `InputStream`.

---

What you are doing at the moment fails because a `Class` object cannot be serialized.

Answer (score 0):

Do a simple HTTP download, rather than URLClassLoader, to get the class into a file. Then decompile that.

(Writing an object to an ObjectOutputStream only saves the data in an *instance* of the object, and even that works only if the object has implemented Serializable. Not what you're looking for here.)